# SQL insert into statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I can't seem to get the insert statement to work, I'm a newbie to sql.
I've used the same code before and it worked so i copied and pasted and
changed the values. Everything else validates and works fine.
The problem is with the uploadInstallData function

Heres a link to the code in text format:
 http://www.bludevelopment.com/php/getdata.txt

Comment: are there any error messages?

Comment: What error are you getting??? Try `echo` your query and execute.. Or post the errors...

Comment: I am not getting any errors, Unless there is a way to print mysql errors. This script is for an iphone app btw, not a webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off try using PDO, secondly it is incorrect the following: 
`"('$_POST[Timestamp]','$_POST[PMINo]',..."`, you should escape the values :
`" ('".$_POST[Timestamp]."','".$_POST[PMINo]."`',...";

Comment: or you can use `'{$_POST[Timestamp]}'` notation

Comment: I used the escape values, but it still didn't work. I am not sure what  PDO is

Comment: @user1899201: Try debugging with var_dump($_POST); to see if the keys are correct and look try to see what error mysql generated, try http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: i checked for errors but i didn't get any, and the variables are indeed correct, i'm stumped.

Comment: tried again and it worked, i think it was a problem with the server. Thanks for the help